# How to run psexec using subprocess.run()?

Tags: python, subprocess, psexec

Here's the script snippet:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.run(["psexec.exe",
                        "\\\\<machine-name>", 
                        "/u", "<machine-name>\\TestAdmin", 
                        "/p", "<password>",
                        "cmd /c dir"], 
                        capture_output=True, 
                        text=True,
                        shell=True)

print(output.stdout)
print(output.stderr)
```

And here's the output I get:

```
E:\python-scripts>python runpsexec.py

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

The system cannot find the path specified.
Connecting to <machine-name>...


Starting PSEXESVC service on <machine-name>...


Connecting with PsExec service on <machine-name>...


Starting cmd /c dir on <machine-name>...


PsExec could not start cmd /c dir on <machine-name>:
```

I also tried passing in the `-s` option to run it as a system account. If I directly run psexec from cmd prompt, I'm able to run the same command and get the right output.

Are there any limitations in running `psexec` via `subprocess.run()`? Or am I missing something?